# \usepackage throws error in .sty file

Tags: texworks

I have a .sty file with all my custom commands that I use (about 30).
For my Bachelor's thesis I wanted to add a few commands, but the file wouldn't compile anymore and throws the following error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 21.1)  
entering extended mode  
(H:/Studium/BA/commands.sty  
! Undefined control sequence.  
l.1 \usepackage  
               {amsmath}  
?
```

and logfile

```
2021-02-03 14:37:16,197+0100 INFO  texify - this process (10816) started by 'miktex-texworks' with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\texify.exe" --pdf --synctex=1 --clean commands.sty  
2021-02-03 14:37:16,235+0100 INFO  texify.core - start process: miktex-tex.exe C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Temp\mik76606\txiversion.tex  
2021-02-03 14:37:16,634+0100 INFO  texify.core - start process: miktex-pdftex --synctex=1 H:/Studium/BA\commands.sty
```

This is the .sty file (without the commands themselves for readability as they are not the source of the error)

```
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{bbm}  
%% commands %%  
\endinput
```

I am using TeXworks with MikTeX, updated in user and administrator mode and using the processing tool "pdfLaTeX + MakeIndex + BibTeX".
About half a year ago, this worked perfectly and I did not change anything in my settings.

I tried around with different processing tools, adding `\documentclass{article}` or `\ProvidesPackage{myPackage}` on top (as suggested on a different thread), but I always get an error on the first line.

Comment: Show the real error message properly formatted together with the lines before and after it. Copy it from the log-file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Apparently LaTeX is run on `commands.sty`, as it is the first file mentioned in the log. TeXworks thinks that `commands.sty` is the main file. So reconfigure TeXworks to run LaTeX on the `tex` file that starts with `\documentclass`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer just did, the 3 line are all that is written to the logfile when I ty to recompile

Comment: well as @gernot wrote: you are trying to compile your sty instead of the tex.

Comment: @gernot where, how do I do that (google only shows links for overleaf)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but for a .sty to be usable, I have to compile it first, right?

Comment: no you don't compile styles.

Comment: See the TeXworks manual: *To tell TEXworks that it should typeset the main document, one adds atthe very beginning of the sub-document the instruction: `% !TeX root = path/main_file.tex`*

Comment: @gernot just found that as well, and for now that works, but if I want to have the same commands for several different documents, that doesn't seam like an optimal solution.

Comment: You compile the main document (containing `\documentclass`) only, all other files are pulled in by `\usepackage`, `\input`, `\include`, ...

Comment: Well, check out the docs of TeXworks and the internet how other people solve it. Probably there is a solution to this common situation. If not, use a different IDE or a TeX-aware editor, or the command-line. IDEs are not always the best solution

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I learned that .sty files have to be complied before you can use them. And just saving and recompiling my main document still throws the same error in my style file as before (duplicate command from some other package)

Comment: forget my last comment, I somehow fucked up somewhere before. Now recompiling my main file updates the style file, so everything works

Comment: Then unlearn this again.

Comment: anyway, thx for the fast replies

Comment: you do not compile or update .sty (or .tex) files they are simply read as text.

Comment: In addition to all the other comments, your log file shows pdftex; when processing any LaTeX code, you need pdflatex.